# FCSA number directive not working in newest version of Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS with the [FCSA Number directive](https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number).

I've a input field and a div showing the actual number from the model:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="well" name="formTest">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number">Number*</label>
            <input type="input" fcsa-number="{ min: 0, max: 100, maxDecimals: 2 }" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter number" ng-model="number" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}" />
        </div>Number:{{number}}</form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['fcsa-number']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.number = 12;
});
```

Note the `ng-model-options` attribute on the input element. It force that the model is first updated when the input field lost focus.

It's working fine in my app using AngularJS version 1.2.1: http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/m30zp4ug/3/.

If I update to version 1.3+, it does no longer work:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/y6Lo72sm/

If I enter a new number in the input field and click outside the field to loose it's focus, the number is not updated in the model and it's doing back to 12. Why?

Comment: Seems to be a bug with the FCSA number directive. Is there functionality you're getting with that directive that can't be achieved with the build in [number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)?

Comment: The ´number filter´ does not invalid a input field if it's not a valid number. Further I need to validate number of decimals, min and max value etc.

Comment: Ah--the input[number] directive ([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)) will give you min/max validation. You'd need to implement your own decimal length validation, though. Either that or fork FCSA and try to fix the 'blur' conflict.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have this same.  I'm using Angular version 1.3.14.  I went ahead and submitted an [issue](https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number/issues/18).

Answer (score 0):

FCSA-Number updates on blur by default, are you performing some other operation onBlur?  I'm not seeing this issue with FCSA-Number and angular 1.3.13.

FCSA-Number seems to not be supported as the folks there aren't responding to any issues or open PR's which is a shame because it's very close to being very useful.  I'm looking to be able to specify a value from my model to be used as min / max but due to scope resolution, that won't work unless min and max are implemented as attributes.

Angular 1.3 introduced the 'fractionSize' argument to their number filter which might help you, it allows you to specify the number of decimal places.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number